# "Long" routing doesn't work with WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a rather *long* routing in a WebAPI application

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/machines/{machineId}/measurements/scopes")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveScopeForMachine(int machineId, [FromBody]ScopeViewModel scopeVM, int? userId, int? locationId)
 {
```

And I always get `404` when trying to post data. To post data, I use MATLAB

```
options = weboptions('MediaType','application/json', 'RequestMethod', 'post');
webwrite('http://localhost:62284/api/machines/1/measurements/scopes', data, options)
```

Another Post method works however just fine, e.g. this one

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/systems/{id}/machine/")]
public IHttpActionResult AddMachineFromSystem(int id, [FromBody]MachineViewModel machineVM)
```

It works even if I try this one here

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/mytest")]
    public IHttpActionResult mytest([FromBody]ScopeViewModel svm)
    {
        SaveScopeForMachine(1, svm, null, null);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Additional information: I have both webapi and mvc

My routing in webapi (probably too overloaded?)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiOverview",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/",
            defaults: null
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithoutId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: null
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

And my application start in global.asax (so yes, I first define the webapiconfig)

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Comment: As a theory, have you tried including the nullable params? userId and locationId? You may be assuming these parameters are optional when they are not.

Comment: It works if I remove both `int?` params, but how can I add them optionally?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any more of your code, I think you may be assuming the params are optional, but they are `nullable`.

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/machines/{machineId}/measurements/scopes")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveScopeForMachine(int machineId, [FromBody]ScopeViewModel scopeVM, int? userId = null, int? locationId = null)
```

Your previous route would still require them to be present, this way they are given a value, so they can be omitted.